# AngularJS after using npm install my app doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, npm, npm-install

I just used the command npm install for a few modules for datetime picker and now I am getting a bunch of errors i've never seen before. I think it has something to do with npm install --save causing some of my json files to require some files in the datetimepicker repo. I couldn't get it to work so I deleted the node module but the errors are still there. Here are the errors:

```
GET http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/node_modules/angular-bootstrap datetimepicker/src/css/datetimepicker.css

GET http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/node_modules/moment/moment.js 

angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker' is not available!
```

Comment: reading your console error's said, that `ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker` can be loaded, make sure that is referenced on your html. or it has the correct name of the module

Comment: oh, thanks! that fixed it